# sql Update column with sum other columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagrid, sql-update

I want to update with sum full datatable data row wise but how?

See what want I do:

[image]

This code only for shown sum data with row-wise but its not working with NULL value.

```
select 
    sum(tc6671 + tf6671 + pc6671 + pf6671 + tc8572 + tf8572 + pc8572 + pf8572 +
        tc6672 + tf6672 + tc6673 + tf6673 + pc6673 + pf6673 + pc6674 + pf6674 + tc5852 + tf5852 +
        tc5853 + tf5853) as Test 
from 
    cmt_7th;
```

But I want to update my specific column with all sum data.

I was tried this code but failed:

```
update cmt_7th 
set roll = sum(tc6671+tf6671+pc6671+pf6671+tc8572+tf8572+pc8572+pf8572+
               tc6672+tf6672+tc6673+tf6673+pc6673+pf6673+
               pc6674+pf6674+tc5852+tf5852+tc5853+tf5853);
```

And I was tried also by this code:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.total = c.tc6671+c.tf6671+c.pc6671+c.pf6671+c.tc8572+c.tf8572+c.pc8572+
              c.pf8572+c.tc6672+c.tf6672+c.tc6673+c.tf6673+c.pc6673+c.pf6673+
              c.pc6674+c.pf6674+c.tc5852+c.tf5852+c.tc5853+c.tf5853
FROM cmt_7th c
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tc6671+tf6671, use coalesce to handle nulls.

Like `coalesce(tc6671,0)+coalesce(tf6671,0)+...`

So your update statement will be something like

```
UPDATE c
    SET c.total = coalesce(c.tc6671,0) + coalesce(c.tf6671,0) + coalesce(c.pc6671,0) 
    + coalesce(c.pf6671,0) + coalesce(c.tc8572,0) + coalesce(c.tf8572,0) 
    + coalesce(c.pc8572,0) + coalesce(c.pf8572,0) + coalesce(c.tc6672,0) 
    + coalesce(c.tf6672,0) + coalesce(c.tc6673,0) + coalesce(c.tf6673,0) 
    + coalesce(c.pc6673,0) + coalesce(c.pf6673,0) + coalesce(c.pc6674,0) 
    + coalesce(c.pf6674,0) + coalesce(c.tc5852,0) + coalesce(c.tf5852,0) 
    + coalesce(c.tc5853,0) + coalesce(c.tf5853,0)
FROM cmt_7th c
```

But if you use `select sum(coalesce(c.tc6671,0) ...` then you will get only 1 row and column with sum of sum of all columns. 
See what I mean here

http://rextester.com/LUIPOW59089

Comment: `ISNULL` ***vs*** `COALESCE` ?